# Looking at impure phenomenon

Tags: minhag, animals, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

This question posits that, as per the extent of my research, the source for pregnant women not gazing at tameh animals is from the sefer kav hayashar 2:7. Which doesn't mention anything about pregnant women but rather says men and women alike should, to put it in brief, guard their eyes.
This being so (that the minhag for women to not look at tameh  animals comes from a source that doesn't mention women), why are zoos a permitted outing? Or rather, why does this minhag/halacha seem to strictly apply to women when they are not mentioned in this segment. For the kav hayashar himself states that even though one can make the beracha on "strange creatures" it is not good to gaze at them.

So assuming that my postulation is correct, why is this practice solely applied to pregnant women?

Comment: Are you asking why most people in general don't hold by this Kav HaYashar as the normative Halacha, or why those who do hold by it generally restrict it to pregnant women?

Comment: The latter. Why is it solely a restriction for women when it doesn't even mention women

Comment: This is superstition. There is nothing wrong with looking at these animals.

Comment: [Some say that she shouldn’t go to a zoo because she shouldn’t look at briyos temeyos, see Shiras Haguf Vhanefesh 237-2, and Invei Hagefen 2-12 (10)](https://dinonline.org/2018/01/21/pregnant-at-the-zoo/)

Comment: I believe that some groups do apply it to children as well, although I don't know if that comes from this source

Comment: Presumably for the same reason pregnant women are more careful about drinking and smoking. Babies and children are more sensitive to negative influences.

Comment: "as per the extent of my research, the source for pregnant women not gazing at tameh animals is from the sefer kav hayashar 2:7" What is the source for this claim?